# d3.csv isn't reading numbers as numbers

Tags: d3.js

If I read a csv file using this code, production, area, and yield are NaN.

```
d3.csv("CA.csv", function(data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = d.date;
      d.production = +d.production;
      d.area = +d.area;
      d.yield = +d.yield;
  });
  console.log(data);
});
```

The following code reads the data, but then it is all stored as text.

```
d3.csv("CA.csv", function(data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = d.date;
      d.production = d.production;
      d.area = d.area;
      d.yield = d.yield;
  });
  console.log(data);
});
```

This is what my data looks like:

```
date,production,area,yield
2015,11886.00,2030.00,58552.00
2016,12864.00,2034.00,63245.00
2017,10743.00,2021.00,53157.00
2018,11235.00,1985.00,56599.00
```

Comment: Could you add a runnable [mre]? It will help us pinpoint the problem and will give you better answers

Comment: Your first code block works fine. Check out the following block and check the console https://bl.ocks.org/akulmehta/cf3ffc7a5b68cfa8c3616afa6c9130c7/